# Twitter Bootstrap plus Isotope gives me weird result

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

I try to integrate Isotope to a Bootstrap project and it doesn't really go well.

Here is some pieces of code to explain :

```
<section id="last" class="row">
  <article class="post span3">
    ...
  </article>
  <article class="post span3">
    ...
  </article>
  <article class="post span3">
    ...
  </article>
</section>

$(function(){
  $('#last').isotope({
    itemSelector : '.post',
    layoutMode : 'fitRows'
  });
});
```

And here is the weird result

[image]

Would you have any idea why it gives me this ? :/

Comment: It's hard to say without being able to look at a live example and see the CSS, etc. Can you post a link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check the `imagesLoaded()` function in Isotope. Maybe the images are not completely loaded before the Isotope init.

```
    $(function(){
        $('#last').imagesLoaded(function(){
            $('#last').isotope({
                itemSelector : '.post',
                layoutMode : 'fitRows'
            });
        });
    });
```

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html

Comment: Yep, it was just that simple, waiting for the images. Thanks :)